# capture image and save it to database with django

Tags: python, django, database, web-applications, webcam

I am trying to make a web app with django in which it clicks an image from the camera and saves the image to a database. How can that be implemented? if there is a source code available, kindly share a link to it. thank you

Comment: did you solve it please ? here is my question if could help me please answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69321252/how-to-capture-image-from-webcam-in-web-browser-model-formset-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came here hoping to find an answer; there not being one, I hereby offer mine ...

The trick is to encode the image and save it as a *TextField*.

The solution I provide is bit clunky in the way the images are read every time *select_image.html* is loaded, but I did that because my requirement is a bit more complex and this does the job. I assume you know how to get the image from the camera (which is equivalent to my reading it from file).

There are two templates, *select_image.html* and *display_image.html*. When *select_image.html* is called for the first time it reads *.png* images from file and saves the images to the database. When an image is selected it is retrieved from the database and displayed in *display_image.html*.

**select_image.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Select Image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select Image</h1>

    {% block content %}
        <ul>
            {% for image in images %}
                <li><a href="display-image/{{ image }}">{{ image }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**display_image.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Display Image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Display Image</h1>

    {% block content %}
        <img id="image" src="{{ image }}" alt="image">
    {% endblock %}
    <p></p>
    <a href="/users/images">Images</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null= False, blank=False, default='image_name', unique=True)
    image = models.TextField()
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('images', views.Images.as_view(), name='images'),
    path('display-image/<str:image_name>/', views.DisplayImage.as_view(), name='display-image'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from PIL import Image as PilImage
import io
import base64
import os
from .models import Image

class Images(View):
    url = "images/select_image.html"

    def get(self, request):
        dir = <image file directory>
        image_names = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
        for image_name in image_names:
            base_path = os.sep.join([dir, image_name])
            path = '.'.join([base_path, 'png'])
            pil_image = PilImage.open(path)
            encoded_image = self._encode_image(pil_image)
            Image.objects.get_or_create(name=image_name, image=encoded_image)
        context = {'images': image_names}
        return render(request, self.url, context)

    @staticmethod
    def _encode_image(image):
        """Return image encoded to base64 from a PIL.Image.Image."""
        io_buffer = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(io_buffer, format='PNG')
        saved_image = io_buffer.getvalue()
        encoded_image = ''.join(['data:image/jpg;base64,', base64.b64encode(saved_image).decode()])
        return encoded_image

class DisplayImage(View):
    url = "images/display_image.html"

    def get(self, request, image_name):
        image = get_object_or_404(Image, name=image_name)
        context = {'image': image.image}
        return render(request, self.url, context)
```